Particle system Alembic/USD export issue
I am facing the export issue for ever type of simulation in blender, tried Alembic/USD for flip fluids, RBD labs for ground destruction, particle system, But nothing is exporting.
Tried all type of settings, tutorials nothing working. I am mentioning all the detail with Blender file, if any one has solution please free feel to comment
Details:
Blender Version(s): 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1 (Specify all versions tested)
Operating System: Windows 10
Particle System Type: Emission(All type tested)
Export Settings: I’ve also attached screenshots of the Alembic/USD export settings I’ve experimented with.
Error Messages (if any): There is no error occurred during any export
Expected Behavior:
The particle system should be exported to the chosen format, preserving the particle positions, rotations, and other relevant attributes.
Baking the particle simulation
Experimenting with different Alembic/USD export settings
Testing with a clean, default Blender profile to rule out add-on conflicts
Have any of you encountered similar problems with particle system exports in recent Blender versions?
Blender File :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lm0JVNRQLNhYXB5oHZYYfJG5-3DLui2g/view?usp=sharing


Particle systems and most physics are application specific, and cannot be directly exported. See duplicate question comment.
